# What is "S400CA.BIN" on my ASUS laptop?

Tags: laptop, bios, asus-laptop

I just bought a 2nd-hand laptop (ASUS vivobook) from a guy; there's this S400CA.BIN right under my C drive; it's 6,293,504 bytes, and seems to come with the laptop.
The guy said it may have to do with the BIOS and OEM information and could be important...

Can I delete it? What good does it do?

Comment: So its 6MB file?  Based on the name, it would be firmware, its safe to delete it.

Answer (score 1):

It's meant to be used with ASUS' updater/flasher to update the BIOS. If your laptop's BIOS is up to date you can safely delete it.